# Element not expanding with content

Tags: css

Basically, I'm trying to get my web page to look like this:

[image]

---

The top layer is a fixed height, the bottom layer is a fixed height, but the middle, white layer should be variable height depending on the amount of content inside the `#middle_wrap` layer.

This is my result unfortunately:

---

[image]

---

I can hear you laughing, stop it!! As you will see by my code, I'm getting away with it by setting the height of the `#middle_sub_layer` to 1500px, which is the height of my content, but this is not ideal - at all! It really needs to be fluid, to fit all the content, whatever the height.

```
#top_sub_layer { height:200px; text-align:center; z-index:1; position:relative; }
#middle_sub_layer { height:1500px; background:#FFF; padding:25px; z-index:1; position:relative; }
#bottom_sub_layer { height:280px; z-index:1; padding:20px; position:relative; }
#middle_wrap { width:960px; margin:0 auto; top:15px; position:relative; z-index:1; }
```

How can I alter this style block to get my desired result? I tried `height:auto`, I tried `height:100%` and I tried `z-index:1` on all the layers. I'm obviously quite new to CSS layouts.

Comment: Try adding `bottom: 0px;` to your #bottom_sub_layer and see

Comment: This is a lot simpler than you're making it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a header with a set height, a footer with a set height, and a middle with variable content, do something like this: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mncp2/). Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#top_sub_layer { height:200px; text-align:center; }
#middle_sub_layer {background:#FFF; padding:25px;}
#bottom_sub_layer { height:280px; padding:20px; }
#middle_wrap { width:960px; margin:0 auto; }
```